# Django request object and function declaration

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm fairly new to Django and one of the things that I am unclear about is how the request object gets included.

For example, in the views.py file in any given app I can declare:

```
def my_func(request):
   do_something(request)
   ...
```

and at this point Django includes the request object. So my questiin is can I include the request object in any other file that I create and Django will do the right thing and automatically include the object?

Answer (score 3):

> can I include the request object in any other file that I create and Django will do the right thing and automatically include the object?

No, **`my_func()` is a view** and receives a `request` object [by definition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/):

> A view function, or view for short, is simply a Python function that takes a Web request and returns a Web response.

You cannot expect an arbitrary function anywhere in the project to receive `request` automagically.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic involved. The view works because it is linked to an url through your url.py file.

If you want you can delcare views in other files, for example viewsmail.py. As long as you link the function to an url in the url file, the funciton will be called with the right request object, regardless of where the function is located.